# Connecting to MS SQL server from a Linux box

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows, kerberos

I am trying to connect to MS SQLServer from an application that I have written (using Qt) which runs on Linux. Here are some details of the setup:

The SQLServer box (SQLBox) is part of my domain (mydomain.local). This domain uses Active Directory running on ADBox.mydomain.local, The Linux box is not part of the domain. The user on the Linux box is logged on locally. ie mvincent@linuxbox.

I have installed kerberos on Linux and configured it to connect to ADBox.mydomain.local. Using kinit mvincent@mydomain.local I get a ticket returned which can be seen using klist. mvincent@mydomain.local is setup with permissions to access SQLServer on SQLBox.

I am using ODBC to connect to SQLServer. SQLServer is configured to accept connections only from ActiveDirectory users. A user name and password cannot be used to connect to the SQLServer. My ODBC connection string includes `Trusted_Connection=yes`

My Qt application will run as the logged on user on Linux. This will be mvincent.LinuxBox. I can't get a ticket for this user, so the connection is refused.

I can get a ticket for mvincent@mydomain.local, but I can't figure out how to enter this ticket or this user into the ODBC connection string.

Can I do what I'm trying to do?  If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to create a login for mvincent.LinuxBox on the SQLBox SQL Server?  You have to first be able to create a login on SQL Server before you can use it.

Comment: Not on the SQL Server - it is configured to use only integrated windows authentication.

Comment: Have you ever managed to find a solution for this? I'm struggling with something similar. I'm able to do `kinit username@domain` successfully, but when I try `sqlcmd -E` (Integrated security/trusted connection with ODBC),  I just get `SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database.`

Comment: @valorl My pragmatic solution was to remove Linux as an operating system for application. My boss at the time just said don't worry about Linux.  It was an application for company internal use.  So, in short, no I never found a solution.